# MySQL query select where columns contains numbers and letters

Tags: mysql

I need to filter a column to get only rows which contain letters and numbers. 
Its because I need to get all real license plates.
License plates are like: AB12CD or AB123C, So they always contain numbers and letters. I don't know how to do this.

First I tried to look if the licenseplate was a number with IsNumeric(licenseplate) = 1 to filter at least all numbers out. But it did not work at all.

```
SELECT licenseplate, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%y'), mileage
FROM auto_new
WHERE LENGTH(licenseplate) = 6
AND IsNumeric(licenseplate) = 1
AND licenseplate NOT LIKE '%#%'
GROUP BY licenseplate, mileage
```

At least I got license plates without #, but how do i filter all other characters?

Comment: Using: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928092/need-a-regex-for-a-string-that-must-have-both-numeric-and-letter-characters  as a diving board... `WHERE Licenseplate REGEXP '^([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)[0-9a-zA-Z]*$'`

Comment: @xQbert Thanks, I think that's the closest to what I need :)

Comment: Is there an specific order for the plates? like it should start with 2 or 3 letters then 2 or 3 numbers and finally 1 or 2 letters, or it is completely arbitrary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

`SELECT licenseplate, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%y'), mileage
FROM auto_new
WHERE licenseplate REGEXP '(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])[\d|\w]*' AND Length(Address) = 6
GROUP BY licenseplate, mileage`

This will make sure only license plates that have a length of 6 and contain only alphanumeric characters are returned.

Comment: It returns the licenseplates I need but also all licenseplates that only contains numbers (and are not 6 characters long)

Comment: This will make sure that at least one letter is present, one number and that the string is 6 characters long.

Comment: '(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).*' AND Length(Address) = 6

Comment: Thanks, used a combination of both the length and the regexp in the comment on my post. It works fine now :D

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions is what you want to go for. Something link this:

```
select licenseplate FROM auto_new
WHERE licenseplate REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]+$'
```